# Rust and misty glass door, repair or replace?

Tags: water, sliding-glass-door, rust

My daughter shoot water gun at our balcony glass door, water got in between glasses, now it's rust and misty.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

We got a handyman to paint walls last week. We let him take a look. He said it has to be replaced.

I want to double check whether it is fixable and worth repairing first. If so, is it something I can do myself and how? Thanks.

Comment: does it get very cold where you live?

Comment: Yes, long and cold winters.

Comment: the window usually is sealed and filled with gas that does not conduct heat as easily as plain air ... your window, as it is now, does not provide much insulation

Comment: Does that mean it is not my daughter'a fault because water shouldn't be able to get in if it is in good condition? And I should replace it?

Comment: my guess is that the seals failed sometime in the past ... it is also possible that the window was never a sealed unit ... unsealed windows tend to get covered with frost on the inside during winter

Comment: If it's a sealed unit (and it's not absolutely clear from your pictures... you'll see a spacer between two panes of glass if it is), then shooting a water gun didn't damage it. It had already failed. Sadly, this needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

The seal would have had to have failed BEFORE your daughter squirted water on it. Her water getting in just alerted you to the problem. Give her a cookie and apologize for making her feel bad...

In general it would cost more to try to clean and reseal it than it would cost to buy new sealed units.

Answer (score 1):

There are some companies who specialized in window repairs like this.  You might consult with one or two local ones and get their opinion.

Generally they drill a small hole, desiccate the interior, and refill with some inert gas.  It can prolong the life of the window but as long as the same process that caused the issue to begin with is present, the window will fail again.

Best best, although a fairly expensive one, is to replace the window entirely.

Comment: Right, replace the glass, not the door.